# How to find specific letter on a string and change the color of it using

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this string from a p element
`<p>This is my string</>`

I want to find a letter "s" in that using js and change the color of it.

Comment: You can use onchange($event) on p tag and get innerHTML of the p tag. After getting the innerHTML you can run conditionals and change it's colour.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's a few parts to what you're trying to accomplish.  You've already gotten your string:

```
const myString = someDOMFunction(); // 'This is my string'
```

Next you need to find the position or "index" of the first `'s'` in that string:

```
const sIndex = myString.indexOf('s'); // 3
```

you can then use that index to split the string into two parts:

```
const leftPart = myString.substr(0, sIndex); // 'Thi'
const rightPart = myString.substr(sIndex + 1); // ' is my string'
```

Finally you can build a string of HTML (and CSS) which includes those two parts, using template string syntax:

```
const html = `${leftPart}<span style="color:red">s</span>${rightPart}`;
```

... and then add that HTML back onto the page, for instance:

```
$('#someElement').innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Just a reminder, you should always accept (ie. click the checkmark next to) the answer that best answered your question, if any ... even if it wasn't mine :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the replace function with a regular expression.

```
const str = "<p>This is my string<p/>";

const newStr = str.replace(/s/g, '<span style="color:blue">s</span>');
```

Remove the `g` flag to replace only the first occurrence.

Making it dynamic:

```
const str = "<p>This is my string<p/>";

function highlight(str, char) {
  const re = new RegExp(char, "g");
  return str.replace(re, `<span style="color:blue">${char}</span>`);
}

const newStr = highlight(str, "s");
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on asliwinski's answer, here's a case-sensitive highlighter:

```
function highlight(str, char) {
    const re = new RegExp(`(${char})`, "gi");
    return str.replace(re, `<span style="background-color:rgb(230,230,230)">$1</span>`);
}
```